# Unable to get response from website's API with Python and requests lib

Tags: python, request, web-crawler

I want to get JSON response from one API that I found on website.

This is the website page:
https://bstger.weblaw.ch/?size=n_60_n

When you click on 'suche' button on the right, and when you go to 'inspect page' and then "network" you will see this API:

https://bstger.weblaw.ch/api/.netlify/functions/searchQueryService

That API contains the data that I want to get, but Im always getting 400.

This is my code:

```
import requests
url = 'https://bstger.weblaw.ch/api/.netlify/functions/searchQueryService'

headers = {"Connection": 'keep-alive',
           "ontent-Type": 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
           "Host": 'bstger.weblaw.ch',
           "Origin": 'https://bstger.weblaw.ch',
           "Referer": 'https://bstger.weblaw.ch/?size=n_60_n'}

response = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, headers=headers) # i have tried it with post but still 400
print("Response for", url, response)
```

I have tried with and without headers, maybe I need to add more values to headers but I do not know what data, maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: First test: visit that page yourself. I tried visiting it in my browser and got a 400 the same as your code does. Trying it after visiting your first link gives me a page that appears to just be perpetually loading. I suspect there are additional parameters you'll have to supply in order for a request to that page to work, as you would probably expect for a search API. (Guesswork as I don't know how to follow the instructions you gave, I don't see "networking" anywhere.)

Comment: When you go 'right click' -> 'inspect' and then 'network' there is a second API link that I posted.

Comment: Ah, in that case you will absolutely need to pass some additional data, likely as POST parameters. You'll need to inspect the full request that is being sent to find out what is going on. I'll also add the mandatory note that what you're doing may be against the terms of use of the site and you should check that.

Comment: I know that, but I do not know where all post parameters

Comment: The quickest way is to click on the request on the Network tab and then go to the Payload tab in the request details.